# How to reduce app size in expo sdk version 36?

Tags: react-native, expo

Even the simplest app built on EXPO sdk v36 is almost 50MB. Is there a way to reduce the size ?.

I was working with EXPO for some time and until sdk v32, the size was not that big and then it all changed. I expected a solution at least in their new version.

Answer (score 1):

do `expo build: android --type app-bundle` to get an android app bundle, this bundle will be optimized by Google for different android versions and are smaller in the end.

When expo updates its react-native version to 0.61, using Hermes should decrease your app size significantly and also decrease TTI by up to 2s. I was at React Native EU conference so this is the latest info.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: "Expo SDK 36 is based on React Native 0.61.4",Are you sure about 0.61?Because Sdk 36 is already on it.

Comment: Yes sure , sorry late to reply but it will work fine .

Comment: Well on expo sdk 36 I'm getting worse results on size.Hermes isn't effecting anything in there.